# Checking if value returned is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple PHP file in which I check if the users email exists in my database using the following code:

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM userData WHERE email = '$email'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Which works perfectly fine when the user enters an email address that is in the database, however, when I want to determine if this $query is null or empty - I'm not sure which one though.

When I enter an email that isn't in the database and add the following code in below:

```
    if(is_null($result)){
    echo 'email not in database';
    }
```

the code in the {} isn't executed.

I was just wondering if you  could help me out.

Hi again,

Sorry for the duplicating another post. I corrected it by using:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{ 
  // a row with email exists 
} 
else 
{
  // no row with particular email exists 
}
```

Comment: `mysql_query` returns the executed query resource. You have to fetch data from resource or count the rows for that.

Comment: Obligatory [don't use mysql_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) functions, especially if you're new :), swap over to something better now and save yourself hours of headache later on

Comment: Just a warning, this is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: there's a big difference between `is_null` and `empty`, especially in MySQL and doing a SELECT all. what you're looking for is `mysql_num_rows()` or `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_rows($result);
if(!$row){
      echo 'email not in database';
}
```

OR

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($num == 0){                                                         
    echo 'email not in database';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check whether your query executed or not by

```
 if($result > 0){
    // perform some action 
 }
```

You should use **mysqli_** instead of **mysql_** as it is deprecated and will be removed in future.

what you need is `mysqli_num_rows()`  to see if atleast 1 row was in the table or not

> for reference - [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{ 
  // a row with email exists 
} 
else 
{
  // no row with particular email exists 
}
```

Comment: You should clarify that you're switching from mysql to mysqli functions (which is the right thing to do).

Comment: Making edit to my answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too !

```
if(empty($result)){
    echo 'email not in database';
}
```

`empty()` will check if `$result` is `null`, or its value is `0`, or if `$result` doesn't exists.

See here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php